# .htaccess and php configuration

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having some trouble to get the right config for .htaccess file.

I made a small site using mvc pattern and all urls look like site.com/appname/public/index.php?param=page. I'm trying to get all url write as site.com/page.
I searched into Apache docs but I'm still confused...

This is what I have now in /public directory:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /appname/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And this is what I have in root dir:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ appname/public [R=301,L]
```

This is working fine, it redirect to index.php (in /public directory) and rewrite all urls into site.com/appname/public/page.

Now I'm triyng to get more and I would hide also /appname/public, but I can't undestand how. 
Should I combine more RewriteRule to match "/appname/public"?

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: more info about what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a directory tree like:

```
htdocs
|---appname
    |
    |---app
    |   |---other_dirs
    |   |---other_files
    |  
    |---public
        |---some_dirs/file
        |--- index.php
```

In order to accesss my pages I need to point browser to index.php and passing some GET value. So, all urls should look like:

```
site.com/appname/public/index.php?val=page
```

This is what I have right now (with rules above)

```
site.come/appname/public/page
```

And this is what I'm trying to get...

```
site.com/page
```

I don't understand how to rewrite/hide also the middle part, keeping the last one with the structure "?url=$1" ("url" will be handled in a controller, parsed and so on).

I hope it's more clear.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question. Please clarify.

Is the RewriteBase directory within the documentroot directory? What are you trying to eliminate?

[Apache Manual Mod_Rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

provides a lot of examples and details on how to manage mod_rewrite

Take a look there first and please respond with more specifics on what your setup looks like.

This is pulled from that page and details why you use rewritebase. Are the folders you wish to truncate all in the htdocs folder or they outside the public docroot or htdocs or www or whatever you have named your document root directory?

```
RewriteBase Directive

Description:    Sets the base URL for per-directory rewrites
Syntax: RewriteBase URL-path
Default:    None
Context:    directory, .htaccess
Override:   FileInfo
Status: Extension
Module: mod_rewrite
The RewriteBase directive specifies the URL prefix to be used for per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule directives that substitute a relative path.

This directive is required when you use a relative path in a substitution in per-directory (htaccess) context unless either of the following conditions are true:

The original request, and the substitution, are underneath the DocumentRoot (as opposed to reachable by other means, such as Alias).
The filesystem path to the directory containing the RewriteRule, suffixed by the relative substitution is also valid as a URL path on the server (this is rare).
In the example below, RewriteBase is necessary to avoid rewriting to http://example.com/opt/myapp-1.2.3/welcome.html since the resource was not relative to the document root. This misconfiguration would normally cause the server to look for an "opt" directory under the document root.

DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
Alias /myapp /opt/myapp-1.2.3

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myapp/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$  welcome.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added more details. The folders I wish truncate are the appname/ and public/, in order to get only the last params just after domain name, something like "site.com/my_page" instead of "site.come/appname/public/my_page".